# I cannot update plugins on a wordpress website running on Debian 11 using the Debian WordPress package

Tags: debian, wordpress

I was tasked with updating a WordPress site, and I am prompted by a ftp/sftp/ssh2 connection window.

Normally if the web folder is owned by Apache, this is not a problem. Let me explain in detail what I've come across.

For starters, this server is using the wordpress debian package, which I am not familiar with. I am use to installing wordpress from their website. I suspect something in the way wordpress is setup, is causing the issue.

I've tried chown -R www-data:www-data website.com, and I still get the ftp connection window on plugin updates. Apache was even restarted.

I've logged out and back in; I've tried different browsers.

Originally the folder is owned by a user in which I put those permissions back. I ran 'id user' command, and I found that the user is part of the www-data group and is part of a sftpusers group.

In the /etc/wordpress folder is a file [www.website.php](http://www.website.php), and it has all of the wordpress information that you would normally find in the standard wordpress installing wp-config.php

There is a section of constants
define('FS_METHOD', 'ssh2');
//define('FS_USER', 'user1');
//define('FS_PASS', 'passwd');

I did run dpkg -s vsftpd, and it is installed, and I ran systemctl status on vsftpd, and it's running.

It must be something in this wp config. I can't post the whold config because of passwords and keys, but that's all that is in here to work with.

another set of eyes would be great thanks.